# Spin the Wheel code - WITHOUT javascript

Tags: html, css, html5-canvas

Looking to build something like this - a spin the wheel - using only HTML and CSS, **without** Javascript

1. http://tpstatic.com/_sotc/sites/default/files/1010/source/roulettewheel.html
2. http://www.dougtesting.net/winwheel

Looking for some references or even to see if it can be done.

Comment: HTML and CSS don't have event handlers, so there is no way to execute CSS animation on click.

Comment: @Justinas You could work off of the `:hover`, `:focus` and `:active` pseudo-selectors.

Answer (score 5):

This is using the Hover effect of spinning. Since css doesn't have event handlers, you can't add/remove classes. However, you can add hover effects:

```css
div {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: gray;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}
div:hover {
  -webkit-animation: spin 0.8s infinite linear;
}
@-webkit-keyframes spin {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
Hover to see effect: <div>Spin</div>
```

---

If you could use a *tiny* bit of javascript, you could do something like this:

```js
$('div').click(function(){
  $(this).toggleClass("thisIsAdded");
  });
```

```css
div {
      height: 100px;
      width: 100px;
      border-radius: 50%;
      background: gray;
      margin: 0 auto;
      text-align: center;
    }
    .thisIsAdded {
      -webkit-animation: spin 0.8s infinite linear;
    }
    @-webkit-keyframes spin {
      0% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
      }
      100% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
      }
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Click to see:<div>spin</div>
```

**Note:**

The script here is *purely* toggling the class 'thisIsAdded'.

Comment: Not what I was looking for, but appreciate the reply. Thanks!

Comment: The 'without javascript' makes this question **physically impossible.** Could I ask why you're not using javascript? Generating 'random numbers' ***requires*** a script of some sort!!

Comment: @user3264603: Are you looking to make something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/H5LKy/181/)? If so it ***really needs*** javascript!

Answer (score 1):

As Justinas pointed out We cant fire css style on click event. You need javascript for that. However you can use CSS animation to achieve the spin effect but only with pseudo-selectors.

below is a sample spin effect using only CSS

```
<style type="text/css">
.content
{
    float:left;cursor:pointer;   
}
.content::after
{
    content:'>';float:right;margin:0 0 0 10px;
    -moz-transition:0.5s all;-webkit-transition:0.5s all;
}
.content:hover::after
{
    -moz-transform:rotate(90deg);-webkit-transform:rotate(90deg);
}

</style>
<body>
    <div class="content">Sample</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Upvote for a nice alternative. IMHO, it still seems unsatisfying that the wheel always rotates to 90 degrees. If it were me...I'd use JS and get a random ending rotation.

Comment: Interesting! Thanks for the reply. If only you could generate a random number using only HTML, then you could rotate it by the random degree everytime.

Comment: @user3264603 unfortunately html cannot generate a random number. its just a markup. If you really need to generate a random and apply to css you have no other option except javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go.. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/juoo9vh4/)

CSS:

```
.circle {
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 10%;
    left: 10%;
    width: 120px;
    height: 120px;
    -webkit-animation:spin 4s linear infinite;
    -moz-animation:spin 4s linear infinite;
    animation:spin 4s linear infinite;
    background: repeating-linear-gradient(
      45deg,
      #606dbc,
      #606dbc 10px,
      #465298 10px,
      #465298 20px
    );
}
@-moz-keyframes spin { 100% { -moz-transform: rotate(360deg); } }
@-webkit-keyframes spin { 100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); } }
@keyframes spin { 100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); transform:rotate(360deg); } }
```

Comment: Not what I was looking for, but appreciate the reply. Thanks!